# Error with SetCookies on IE8

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer-8

the following code doesn't work on IE8, when I invoke a method in controller using Ajax.

alert(document.cookie) doesn't show anything.

Controller: player.php

```
public function checkPassword()
    {
        $this->writeLog(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' : Protected video', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/logs/debug_" . date("Y-m-j") . ".log");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        session_start();
        $password = (isset($_SESSION['password']) && !empty($_SESSION['password'])) ? $_SESSION['password'] : $this->getVodPwd($this->input->get('id'),$this->input->get('client'),$this->input->get('source'));
        $name = (isset($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])) ? $_SESSION['name'] : $this->input->get('name');
        if ($name && $password && $this->input->get('pass') == $password) {
            $this->writeLog(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' : Valid password for ' . $name, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/logs/debug_" . date("Y-m-j") . ".log");
            setcookie("unlocked" . $name, "true", time() + $this->config->item('allow_protected_video_access'), "/");
            session_destroy();
            echo "access allowed";
        } else {
            $this->writeLog(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' : Wrong password for ' . $name, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/logs/debug_" . date("Y-m-j") . ".log");
            echo "access denied";
        }
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click','#submit-form-mail',function(){
        if ($('#input-video-password').val() !== ""){
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>player/checkPassword",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    id:'<?php echo $videoId; ?>',
                    source:'<?php echo $source; ?>'
                },
                dataType: "text",
                crossDomain: true,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie',  'PHPSESSID=<?php echo $unique; ?>');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === "access denied") {
                        $('#input-video-password').css({borderColor: "red", borderWidth: "1px"}).val("").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo $translate['wrong-password'] ?>');
                    } else {
                        alert(document.cookie);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can be multiple things. Maybe your privacy settings are blocking the cookie. Your php page could be considered cross domain. Maybe the name you're using is too long for IE8 (max 16 chars or something). The expires date has to be in UTC format, etc.